# CUDA testing in Julia - very low GPU utilization

Tags: windows, julia, gpu

I have been trying to set up CUDA computing under Julia for my RTX 2070 GPU and, so far, I did not get any errors related to failed CUDA initialization when executing CUDA-parallelized code. However, the parallelized computations seem surprisingly slow, so I launched `Pkg.test("CUDA")` from Julia to get some more insight into why that could be. Here is a screenshot of some of the results:
[Julia CUDA test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhNN2.png). The GPU allocation appears to be entirely negligible as compared to the CPU.

This is also reflected in the CUDA vs. CPU usage — running `nvidia-smi` shows 0% volatile GPU-util, while the CPU in the resource monitor was consistently at 80% and more usage throughout the test.

Further, the CUDA utilization graph in the task manager merely shows spikes in CUDA utilization rather than continuous usage: [Screenshot of CUDA utilization in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM2i9.png).

Any suggestions for why this could be the case? I have went through the verification of proper CUDA package and driver installation several times now, and I am unsure what to do next.

Comment: Julia code takes a very significant amount of time to compile for CUDA. From what you have written in your post it looks like you have been benchmarking the CUDA code compilation process (this always happens when you run any function only once).

Comment: I guess the spikes are the actual GPU operations and the rest is all Julia side operations to make those spikes happen.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Thanks for the comment! I was under the impression that every test in ```Pkg.test("CUDA")``` was meant to execute a large batch of CUDA computations for a given Julia function. Are you saying that the several GB of CPU allocations versus the 0.00 MB of GPU allocations (visible in the first screenshot) reflects the costly compilation process? I assumed that there would be at least one test in that testing suite which would put the GPU under extensive load, but none of the tests ended up doing so.

Comment: @t3tcbr: Looking at the code (first time I have even seen Julia code, btw) for some of the tests in your screen shots, they are tiny, toy examples for the most part. They look like they are there to exercise the compilation infrastructure and codebase and confirm that it all works. Not "put the GPU under extensive load". I think you have unrealistic expectations of what this is intended for

Comment: I have been running many times bechmarks where compilation was 30s vs 30 microseconds to run the actual benchmark on GPU (million times difference). Hence, unless you properly benchmark, all information is irrelevant. And since you are not sure - the benchmarking is the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

As the comments note, the tests in [Cuda.jl/test](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/CUDA.jl/tree/master/test) are designed to test the compilation pipeline, not really to put the GPU under any significant load. Just to complete the picture, if you do want to try loading the GPU, you might try modifying an example from https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/tutorials/introduction/, for example along the lines of

```
N = 2^20
using CUDA

x_d = CUDA.fill(1.0f0, N)  # a vector stored on the GPU filled with 1.0 (Float32)
y_d = CUDA.fill(2.0f0, N)  # a vector stored on the GPU filled with 2.0

for i=1:100000
    y_d .+= sqrt.(x_d)
end
```